# Wildcard 301 subfolder redirect to query with character replacement

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, replace, character, wildcard

I need to use .htaccess file to do a wildcard 301 redirect from folder to query with replacement of characters.

I need all folders after mydomain.com/XXX/ redirected but with the hyphens in the subfolder names changed to plus signs.

Example...

mydomain.com/XXX/**all-subfolders**/

redirects to

mydomain.com/XXX/**?s=all+subfolders**

So what I am essentially doing is turning all folders after the XXX folder into search queries with all "-" replaced with "+".

So if someone clicks on a link to:

mydomain.com/XXX/**cold-beer**/

they get redirected to the search query

mydomain.com/XXX/**?s=cold+beer**

If this is possible, I would appreciate some solutions.

This is for a WP site if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did my answer work for you Chuck? Please accept it if it did using the tick at the top left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 7 days of pulling my hair out, I finally found an answer.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /XXX/(.*)-(.*) http://example.com/XXX/$1+$2
RedirectMatch 301 /XXX/(.*)\/ http://example.com/XXX/?s=$1
```

You have to do it this way in wordpress instead of

```
RewriteRule ^XXX\/(.*)-(.*) XXX/$1+$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^XXX/(.*)\/ XXX/?s=$1 [R=301]
```

because wordpress default rewrite rules will override the above and you can't take the default wordpress rules out as it will render all of your pages & posts inaccessible.

So my .htaccess file looks like...

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RedirectMatch 301 /XXX/(.*)-(.*) http://example.com/XXX/$1+$2
RedirectMatch 301 /XXX/(.*)\/ http://example.com/XXX/?s=$1
```

So now,
**example.com/XXX/cold-beer/** redirects to **example.com/XXX/?s=cold+beer**,
**example.com/XXX/what-ever/** redirects to **example.com/XXX/?s=what+ever**
and so on.

As far as I know, you need both lines.  The first line only converts one "-" (the last one).  The second line replaces the rest of the "-" and removes the trailing "/" that the wordpress rewrites add to the end of the URL when you have "pretty permalinks" set in your permalinks settings.

The down side to this, regardless of which method above you use, is that each conversion of a "-" to a "+" is a redirect in and of itself so if you have 12 characters to replace in a URL, that's 12 redirects.  In my situation that's not huge a problem, but it might be for some.

I hope this helps someone else because I can't tell you how many hours I have wasted with this.  I'm not a developer in any way, shape or form.

If someone has a better way that's wordpress friendly, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the first part:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/?s=$2
```

As for converting the dashes to plus signs, I suggest you do that in the script rather than in the rewrite, which is not ideal for such things. It could map it through a custom script, but you might as well just do it in your existing search script, and is a better solution. You could add a parameter "needs-translation" so you know which queries need processing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/?s=$2&needs-translation=1
```

If you really want/need to do it in the rewrite, have a look at [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) using the [prg](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) option. Read the warnings about performance and risks.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  As for the first part you posted, it doesn't work.  When I put it in my .htaccess it does nothing.  Can't test the second part till I get the first part working.  Also, yes, I do need to do this in .htaccess as I cannot mess with the search function for now.

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable your .htaccess file with `AllowOverride all` in your main config?

Comment: Not sure.  But I found a solution and posted it below.  Thanks for you help.